# Throttling with SemaphoreSlim -- "Task.Run()" vs "new Func<Task>()"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

This might not be specific to SemaphoreSlim exclusively, but basically my question is about whether there is a difference between the below two methods of throttling a collection of long running tasks, and if so, what that difference is (and when if ever to use either).

In the example below, let's say that each tracked task involves loading data from a Url (totally made up example, but is a common one that I've found for SemaphoreSlim examples).

The main difference comes down to how the individual tasks are added to the list of tracked tasks.  In the first example, we call `Task.Run()` with a lambda, whereas in the second, we new up a  `Func(<Task<Result>>())` with a lambda and then immediately call that func and add the result to the tracked task list.

### Examples:

### Using Task.Run():

```
 SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(_concurrentTasks);
 List<string> urls = ImportUrlsFromSource();

 List<Task<Result>> trackedTasks = new List<Task<Result>>();
        foreach (var item in urls)
        {
            await ss.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                try
                {
                    return await ProcessUrl(item);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _log.Error($"logging some stuff");
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    ss.Release();
                }
            }));
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(trackedTasks);
```

### Using a new Func:

```
 SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(_concurrentTasks);
 List<string> urls = ImportUrlsFromSource();

 List<Task<Result>> trackedTasks = new List<Task<Result>>();
        foreach (var item in urls)
        {
            trackedTasks.Add(new Func<Task<Result>>(async () =>
            {
                await ss.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                try
                {
                    return await ProcessUrl(item);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _log.Error($"logging some stuff");
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    ss.Release();
                }
            })());
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(trackedTasks);
```

Comment: It might be a lot easier to not reinvent the wheel and just use PLinQ:`var results = urls.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(_concurrentTasks).Select(SyncDownLoadMethod).ToList()`.

Comment: Fair enough.  But I'm still curious about the fundamental question here -- what is the actual difference in how those examples work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two differences:

---

### Task.Run does error handling

First off all, when you call the lambda, it runs. On the other hand, `Task.Run` would call it. This is relevant because `Task.Run` does a bit of work behind the scenes. The main work it does is handling a faulted task...

If you call a lambda, and the lambda throws, it would throw before you add the `Task` to the list...

However, in your case, because your lambda is async, the compiler would create the `Task` for it (you are not making it by hand), and it will correctly handle the exception and make it available via the returned `Task`. Therefore **this point is moot**.

---

### Task.Run prevents task attachment

`Task.Run` sets `DenyChildAttach`. This means that the tasks created inside the `Task.Run` run independently from (are not synchronized with) the returned `Task`.

For example, this code:

```
List<Task<int>> trackedTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
var numbers = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var x = 0;
        (new Func<Task<int>>(async () =>{x = item; return x;}))().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        return x;
    }));
}
var results = await Task.WhenAll(trackedTasks);
```

Will output the numbers from 0 to 4, in unknown order. However the following code:

```
List<Task<int>> trackedTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
var numbers = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    trackedTasks.Add(new Func<Task<int>>(async () =>
    {
        var x = 0;
        (new Func<Task<int>>(async () =>{x = item; return x;}))().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        return x;
    })());
}
var results = await Task.WhenAll(trackedTasks);
```

Will output the numbers from 0 to 4, in order, every time. This is odd, right? What happens is that the inner task is attached to outer one, and executed right away in the same thread. But if you use `Task.Run`, the inner task is not attached and scheduled independently.

This remain true even if you use `await`, as long as the task you `await` does not go to an external system...

What happens with external system? Well, for example, if your task is reading from an URL - as in your example - the system would create a `TaskCompletionSource`, get the `Task` from it, set a response handler that writes the result to the `TaskCompletionSource`, make the request, and return the `Task`. This `Task` is not scheduled, it running on the same thread as a parent task makes no sense. And thus, it can break the order.

Since, you are using `await` to wait on an external system, **this point is moot too**.

---

### Conclusion

I must conclude that these are equivalent.

If you want to be safe, and make sure it works as expected, even if - in a future version - some of the above points stops being moot, then keep `Task.Run`. On the other hand, if you really want to optimize, use the lambda and avoid the `Task.Run` (very small) overhead. However, that probably won't be a bottleneck.

---

### Addendum

When I talk about a task that goes to an external system, I refer to something that runs outside of .NET. There a bit of code that will run in .NET to interface with the external system, but the bulk of the code will not run in .NET, and thus will not be in a managed thread at all.

The consumer of the API specify nothing for this to happen. The task would be a promise task, but that is not exposed, for the consumer there is nothing special about it.

In fact, a task that goes to an external system may barely run in the CPU at all. Futhermore, it might just be waiting on something exterior to the computer (it could be the network or user input).

The pattern is as follows:

1. The library creates a `TaskCompletionSource`.
2. The library sets a means to recieve a notification. It can be a callback, event, message loop, hook, listening to a socket, a pipe line, waiting on a global mutex... whatever is necesary.
3. The library sets code to react to the notification that will call `SetResult`, or `SetException` on the `TaskCompletionSource` as appropiate for the notification recieved.
4. The library does the actual call to the external system.
5. The library returns `TaskCompletionSource.Task`.

**Note**: with extra care of optimization not reordering things where it should not, and with care of handling errors during the setup phase. Also, if a `CancellationToken` is involved, it has to be taken into account (and call `SetCancelled` on the `TaskCompletionSource` when appropiate). Also, there could be tear down necesary in the reaction to the notification (or on cancellation). *Ah, do not forget to validate your parameters.*

Then the external system goes and does whatever it does. Then when it finishes, or something goes wrong, gives the library the notification, and your `Task` is sudendtly completed, faulted... (or if cancellation happened, your `Task` is now cancelled) and .NET will schedule the continuations of the task as needed.

**Note**: async/await uses continuations behind the scenes, that is how execution resumes.

*Incidentally, if you wanted to implement SempahoreSlim yourself, you would have to do something very similar to what I describe above. You can see it in my [backport of SemaphoreSlim](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/blob/master/Core/System/Threading/SemaphoreSlim.net35.cs#L187).*

---

Let us see a couple of examples of promise tasks...

1. `Task.Delay`: when we are waiting with `Task.Delay`, the CPU is not spinning. This is not running in a thread. In this case the notification mechanism will be an OS timer. When the OS sees that the time of the timer has elapsed, it will call into the CLR, and then the CLR will mark the task as completed. What thread was waiting? none.
2. `FileStream.ReadSync`: when we are reading from storage with `FileStream.ReadSync` the actual work is done by the device. The CRL has to declare a custom event, then pass the event, the file handle and the buffer to the OS... the OS calls the device driver, the device driver interfaces with the device. As the storage device recovers the information, it will write to memory (directly on the specified buffer) via DMA technology. And when it is done, it will set an interruption, that is handled by the driver, that notifies the OS, that calls the custom event, that marks the task as completed. What thread did read the data from storage? none.

A similar pattern will be used to download from a web page, except, this time the device goes to the network. How to make an HTTP request and how the system waits for a response is beyond the scope of this answer.

It is also possible that the external system is another program, in which case it would run on a thread. But it won't be a managed thread on your process.

---

Your take away is that these task do not run on any of your threads. And their timing might depend on external factors. Thus, it makes no sense to think of them as running in the same thread, or that we can predict their timing (well, except of course, in the case of the timer).

Comment: That's a super helpful explanation.  Quick follow up to make sure I understand -- with an external system and an async call, the fact that the returned Task is not scheduled just means that it can run on any thread and is not synchronized right?  And that fact (the non-scheduled/ordered running in an external system) is "automatic" in that it just happens without me needing to specify it, correct?

Comment: I guess essentially I'm wondering if you could expand on what you mean by "This Task is not scheduled, it running on the same thread as a parent task makes no sense. And thus, it can break the order."

Comment: @istrupin expanded answer. Hopefully it covers your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Both are not very good because they create the tasks immediately. The func version is a little less overhead since it saves the `Task.Run` route over the thread pool just to immediately end the thread pool work and suspend on the semaphore. You don't need an async `Func`, you could simplify this by using an async method (possibly a local function).

But you should not do this at all. Instead, use a [helper method that implements a parallel async foreach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/).

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current); 
        })); 
}
```

Then you just go `urls.ForEachAsync(myDop, async input => await ProcessAsync(input));`

Here, the tasks are created on demand. You can even make the input stream lazy.

Comment: Just to confirm -- what is the advantage in performance that I get using parallel async foreach instead of using an async method with the semaphore?  Is it that I am no longer spending resources actually creating the tasks?  I want to make sure I understand the actual benefit is all.

Comment: Yes, the semaphore version creates tasks. The semaphore also maintains a queue of tasks to activate next. Also, all this machinery is just unnecessary code and it's complicated. Hard to understand and verify to be correct. You want a foreach, use a foreach. Unfortunately, the framework does not have it so you need to copy this small helper into each new project.